# Weird results in ANOVA: the three-way interaction has a pvalue of exactly 1

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models

I am running a three way interaction, predicting 'judgment' from 'factor_1' (between subject, two levels), 'factor_2' (between subject, two levels) and factor_3 (within subject, two levels). I have 120 participants (30 in each level of factor_1 and factor_2)

```
model <- aov(
  judgment ~ factor_1*factor_2*factor_3 +
    Error(participant/factor_3),
  data = MyData)
summary(model)
```

I got a strange 3 way interaction result: the Sum Sq, Mean Sq, and F value have a value of (exactly) 0, and the p value is 1.

How is it possible?

Here are my data:

```
MyData = structure(list(participant = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 
37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 
43L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 
50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 
56L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 
63L, 63L, 64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 
69L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 
76L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 80L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 
82L, 83L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 86L, 87L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 
89L, 89L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 
95L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 100L, 101L, 
101L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 105L, 105L, 106L, 106L, 
107L, 107L, 108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 
112L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 117L, 117L, 
118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 120L), .Label = c("101", "102", 
"103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
"130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
"139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
"166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
"175", "176", "177", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", 
"185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", 
"194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", 
"203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", 
"212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", 
"221"), class = "factor"), factor_1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"P"), class = "factor"), factor_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), factor_3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("HighLoss", 
"LowLoss"), class = "factor"), judgment = c(10L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 
10L, 8L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 
7L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 
6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 
8L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 8L, 5L, 
9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 
9L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 
10L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 
7L, 2L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-240L), .Names = c("participant", "factor_1", "factor_2", "factor_3", 
"judgment"))
```

Comment: The results are perfectly determined.  If you have the model you will know exactly what the value is for each observation meaning the predicted will always equal the observed. (You can look at the fitted results to see that this is true.) You have to have more degrees of freedom than parameters estimated. Don't use a model with every possible interaction of factors where you only have two observations per unit.

Comment: The three-way interaction does not mean that the results determined

Comment: This is really a stats question rather than a programming one, and I think you'll get a better explanation at stats.stackexchange.com [stats.se].

Comment: Thanks, I'll try there